# OpenERP/Odoo create sale.order with specified product id?

Tags: odoo, xml-rpc

Since xml-rpc documentation for OpenERP/Odoo is poor, can someone give an answer on how to create a sale.order in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the method to create a new order and the other method to create the order lines

```
 function createNewOrder($params,$model_name)
    {
        $client = new xmlrpc_client($this->server . "object");
        $client->return_type = 'phpvals';

        $msg = new xmlrpcmsg('execute');

        $nval = array();
        foreach($params as $k=>$v){
            $nval[$k] = new xmlrpcval( $v, xmlrpc_get_type($v) );
        }
        $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($this->database, "string"));  //* database name */
        $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($this->uid, "int"));
        $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($this->password, "string"));
        $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($model_name, "string"));
        $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval("create", "string"));
        $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($nval, "struct"));
        //$msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($orderPrd, "struct"));

        $resp = $client->send($msg);
        //$order_id_line[] = $this->$resp->value()->scalarval();

        if ($resp->errno != 0)
            trigger_error("sock_execute error " . $resp->errstr);
        return $resp->value();
    }


    function createOrderLine($params,$model_name){

        $client = new xmlrpc_client($this->server . "object");
        $client->return_type = 'phpvals';

        $msg = new xmlrpcmsg('execute');
        $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($this->database, "string"));  //* database name */
        $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($this->uid, "int"));
        $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($this->password, "string"));
        $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($model_name,"string"));
        $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval("create", "string"));
        $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($params, "struct"));

        $res = $client->send($msg);

        return $res;

    }
```